# js game freezes with no error

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a javascript game that involves building, destroying, and survival.
It has been working fine but after adding trees the game would randomly freeze after breaking blocks.
The code is here:

```
for (var bl in blocks) {
           if (mouse.x >= blocks[bl].x-camera.x && mouse.y >= camera.y+blocks[bl].y && mouse.x <= blocks[bl].x-camera.x+64 && mouse.y <= camera.y+blocks[bl].y+64) {
                document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
                if (mouse.down) {
                     if (!blocks[bl].d && blocks[bl].d !== 0) {
                          blocks[bl].d = 32;
                     } else if (blocks[bl].d > 0) {
                          blocks[bl].d -= 0.5;
                          if (tools[player.tool].n === 'axe') {
                               blocks[bl].d -= 1;
                          }
                     } else {
                          var fb = false;
                          for (var i in inventory) {
                               if (inventory[i].n === blocks[bl].n) {
                                    inventory[i].a ++;
                                    fb = true;
                               }
                          }
                          if (!fb) {
                               inventory.push({n: blocks[bl].n, a: 1});
                          }
                          blocks.splice(bl, 1);
                     }
                }
           }
      }
```

I don't see any way there could be an infinite loop and no errors show up when it happens.

**EDIT**

I changed the code to

```
          var spliceblock = {bl: 0, s: false};
          for (var bl in blocks) {
               if (mouse.x >= blocks[bl].x-camera.x && mouse.y >= camera.y+blocks[bl].y && mouse.x <= blocks[bl].x-camera.x+64 && mouse.y <= camera.y+blocks[bl].y+64) {
                    document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
                    if (mouse.down) {
                         if (!blocks[bl].d && blocks[bl].d !== 0) {
                              blocks[bl].d = 32;
                         } else if (blocks[bl].d > 0) {
                              blocks[bl].d -= 0.5;
                              if (tools[player.tool].n === 'axe') {
                                   blocks[bl].d -= 1;
                              }
                         } else {
                              var fb = false;
                              for (var i in inventory) {
                                   if (inventory[i].n === blocks[bl].n) {
                                        inventory[i].a ++;
                                        fb = true;
                                   }
                              }
                              if (!fb) {
                                   inventory.push({n: blocks[bl].n, a: 1});
                              }
                              spliceblock.s = true;
                              spliceblock.bl = bl;
                              //blocks.splice(bl, 1);
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
          if (spliceblock.s) {
               blocks.splice(spliceblock.bl, 1);
          }
```

but it still freezes randomly when trying to break blocks.

Comment: you are modifying the `blocks` (array/list?) - by using `.splice(...)` - while you are iterating over it. This is bound to create issues...

Comment: Thanks. I'll try a fix.

Comment: do you see any errors show up in console?

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: Do you have a working demo which you could link to?

Comment: not at the moment, but I don't think this could be caused by anything outside that code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Modifying an array (using splice) while you're iterating through it is bound to cause problems.  If you remove the block bl from the array and then continue to run through it, the counter will probably be off.

Instead, store the index of the block you're removing, then remove it after you're done looping through the blocks.

Comment: still does it after I changed the code. see my edit.